# Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URL . admin page

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

I am a beginner with flask and SQL . I  am trying to create a admin page to enter data into database

```
@app.route("/admin/jobs",methods=['post'])
def add():
  data=request.form
  add_admin_to_db(data)
```

```
def add_admin_to_db(job_id,data):
    row = {
        
        "title": data["title"],
        "loacation": data["location"],
        "salary": data["salary"],
        "requirement": data["requirement"],
        
    }
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        query = text(
            "INSERT INTO jobs (title,location,salary,requirement) VALUES (:title,:location,:salary,:requirement)")
        
        conn.execute(query, row)
        conn.commit()
```

Comment: Ok, and what is your question? Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: im getting method not allowed